# How to change the header items in a Navigation Header Programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, imageview, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to change the text and image in the Navigation Drawer's Header programmatically to display the sign in information, but I keep getting this [error](https://gist.github.com/NovaViper/7ce703cc7f304c7d6fd740d8c5888dd0) (I put it on gist since it was really long); I created [this issue](https://github.com/NovaViper/TrinityLocker/issues/1) on Github with here in the coding the error occurs at.
I created the view using the activity creation wizard that Android Studio has in order to create the entire navigiation drawer Activity.

Does anyone know how can can solve this issue?
I am still new to this, so I may end up asking alot of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get a reference to the `Header` and then find the required views inside the Header. See code below :

```
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
navImageView= (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.nav_image_view);
navTextView = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.nav_text_view);
```